# Coercing ncdf4 to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, netcdf4

I'm trying to wrestle some netcdf files containing daily climate data into .csv files. This is usually a routine task but I got this set of files that seems problematic. The error occurred (see below) where I needed to convert the matrices to dataframe and I couldn't figure out what the issue is. The error doesn't occur when I'm not looping through the files. Any tips would be appreciated.

Here's my code. Sample data can be found here  [sample data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sdj6OMv2WQZk7BaTBjTZrZOJdA7VgQ0i?usp=sharing).

```
library(stringr)
library(ncdf4)

fin <- list.files("D:/path/prec", pattern = ".nc$", full.names=TRUE)
fin2 <- gsub("D:/path/prec/", "", fin)
var_name =  str_replace(fin2, ".nc", "")   ## generates data file names

for(i in seq_along(fin)){
 
 prec <- nc_open(fin[i])
 
 var = ncvar_get(prec, var_name[i], collapse_degen = F)
 dim_lon <- ncvar_get(prec, "longitude")
 dim_lat <- ncvar_get(prec, "latitude")
 dim_time <- ncvar_get(prec, "time")
 
 
 coords = as.matrix(expand.grid(dim_lon, dim_lat, dim_time))
 r = data.frame(cbind(coords, var))  **this is where the problem is!**
 
 
 names(r) = c("Lon", "Lat", "Day", "Prec")
 
 i = var_name[i] ##assign name to match input name 

 write.csv(prec, file.path("D:/path/prec", paste0(i, ".csv")), row.names = FALSE)

}
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
> cannot coerce class ‘"ncdf4"’ to a data.frame.

Expected outcome:

```
 Lon     Lat     Day    Prec
-133.25 60.25   127 10.74618626
-133    60.25   127 11.28547573
-132.75 60.25   127 11.23372364
-132.5  60.25   127 11.06846809
-132.25 60.25   127 10.87025547
-132    60.25   127 9.392285347
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a different approach using `tidync`, which solved the problem. The new approach is more efficient than my original code.

```
library(stringr)
library(tidync)

fin <- list.files("D:/path/prec", pattern = ".nc$", full.names=TRUE)
fin2 <- gsub("D:/path/prec/", "", fin)

var_name =  str_replace(fin2, ".nc", "")     ## generates data file names


for(i in seq_along(fin)) {
 
  prec <- tidync(fin[i])
  prec = prec %>%
    hyper_tibble()
  
  names(prec) = c("Prec", "Lon", "Lat", "Time")
  
  i = var_name[i]             ##assign name to match input name 
  
 write.csv(prec, file.path("D:/path/prec", paste0(i, ".csv")), row.names = FALSE)

}
```

Here's the output

```
#    Prec        Lon    Lat       Time
# 0.0000122     -141    69.6    284038200
# 0.00000904    -141    69.6    284038200
# 0.00000805    -141    69.6    284038200
# 0.00000732    -141    69.6    284038200
# 0.00000244    -140    69.6    284038200
# 0.00000316    -140    69.6    284038200
```

Note that the time is supposed to be in days but this is how it's presented in the source file and has nothing to do with the extraction method. Any tips for conversion would be appreciate.

Comment: What units are those "Time" values e.g. seconds, minutes, hours? Adding a line to your loop with simple arithmetic may solve your issue. If those values are seconds, add something like `prec$Time <- prec$Time / 86400`.

Comment: The time was initially in hours, and then I used `cdo (climate data operator)` to compile the data to daily data from hourly data. So, that changed the time. Do you have a suggestion for conversion from hour to day?

Comment: If your "Time" values are hours, to convert to days use `prec$Time <- prec$Time / 24`

Comment: I don't think that would solve it. A quick division of the value shown here with `24` resulted in something that is still unfamiliar.

Comment: What's the ballpark range of values that you are expecting e.g. 10 days? Do you mean dates instead of days?

Comment: It's supposed to be 365 days. You might be correct about the time being dates. I'm running a code that would finish in a few minutes. I will check the original data to confirm that.

Comment: It's in hours. Here's a line from the dimension info `units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0`

Comment: `lubridate()` is a useful package to handling dates and times. Hope it helps